# Running a C++ binary on the shell via PHP: Can it be loaded into a buffer?

Tags: php, laravel, shell, ubuntu

I have a PHP application (made with Laravel) that saves a user uploaded image to an uploads directory, then executes a C++ compiled binary (in Ubuntu) from the shell that scans the image and returns information about it.

For every image uploaded I'm running the following:

```
// run the binary on the uploaded image

$exec_command = base_path() . '/my_binary ' . storage_path('uploads/') . $fileName . ' 2>&1'; // '2>&1' returns the output from the shell

$output = shell_exec($exec_command);

$output = json_decode($output); // the output is returned as JSON
```

Is this the best way to do this? I've read that it might be better to load my binary into a buffer so it doesn't need to be loaded into memory every time, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: That question is about php and has nothing to do with c++. It doesn't matter in your case if that executable was generated using c++, c, delphi or any other language.

Comment: You can use this http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php, or you can create an extension https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-php-extension-development-via-php-cpp/

Comment: Then don't execute the binary with PHP at all. Run it as a daemon/service and connect to it.